# Beginner Javascript Form

Tags: javascript

I have a simple form that i am trying to submit, but i cannot manage to get any values from it.

I have seen multiples examples but none of them seem to be working.

This is my html:

```
<form name="myForm" action="grade.html" method="get">
        <label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="fname">
        <br>
        <p>Is the Earth Round or Flat?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="earth" value="round">Round<br>
        <input type="radio" name="earth" value="flat">Flat
        <p>What month is the Earth closest to the sun?</p>
        <select name="sf"> 
            <option value="jan" >January</option>
            <option value="feb" >February</option>
            <option value="jul" >July</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

This is my javascript in the grade.html. Here I get nothing shown on the document.write() function.

```
            var grade = 0;

            var form = document.forms[0];
            //var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
            //var e = document.forms["myForm"]["earth"].value;
            //var s = document.forms["myForm"]["sf"].value;

            document.write(form);
            document.write(form.elements[0]);
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong, but none of them are working.

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem? How/where is the code executed / located in relation to the form?

Comment: That Javascript isn't going to do much by itself. And there is no Javascript attached to the form, so it seems, so it will just post its data to `grade.html` when you click the button. Have you tried making the form work without Javascript? That's always the best way to start, because you have less dependencies (only HTML and serverside), and it's easier to debug (just check output instead of Ajax results).

Comment: [`Each web page loaded in the browser has its own document object.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document) So your `grade.html.` knows nothing about any forms.

Comment: You need to reference your js function in the html form and also the javascript file inside script tags at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

The grade.html page in itself has no form, so the javascript there does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in JavaScript, one way is to bind to the "submit" event for your form.

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="processForm()">
    ...
</form>

function processForm() { 
    document.write(document.forms[0].earth.value);
}
```

The JavaScript code (above) should be in the same file as the form, or included as a script from that file.

Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/53bvke8w/1/